# How to accept cookies within Stackoverflow homepage using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to accept cookies with *Selenium*, but the accept button is not found. I am not familiar with *Selenium* and I don't know how to debug. For instance, if I try to accept cookies from *stackoverflow.com*.

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'flex--item')]/div[text()='Accept all cookies']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "flex--item s-btn s-btn__filled js-cookie-settings"))).click()
```

Whatever the selected option (Xpath or CSS), the button is not found. How can I debug my Xpath or CSS selector ? What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element <kbd>Accept all cookies'</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`normalize-space()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Accept all cookies']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Accept all cookies')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```